# Transferring Data from columns based on specific values.

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a column of numbers in excel that I need to separate based on specific value in another column.

Up till now I have used a long winded way of copying and deleting but I'd like to be able to write a formula that achieves it.

I can write this formula which places the value in another column for me but I also want the value to be deleted from the original column.

=IF(P625="OR",(I625),0).

Can I write something on the end of this formula that will delete the value from I625?

Comment: No, A formula cannot affect the value of another cell.  You will need vba to do what you want.

Comment: Ouch.  Not sure I can do that!.  Maybe there is another way I can achieve this go9ing about it differently? Maybe when the Colum goes to the pivot table I can do something there.

Comment: My data is in two columns. First column has the $values for a number of different types of fruit. Second column has the delineations for each type of fruit eg OR for oranges.  I need to get the value for the oranges out of the column with all the other fruit and into a column on its own.

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

running this short macro:

```
Sub Oranges()
    i = 1
    For Each r In Columns(2).SpecialCells(2)
        If r.Value = "OR" Then
            r.Offset(0, -1).Copy Cells(i, 3)
            r.Offset(0, -1).Clear
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

The version may meet your needs:

```
Sub Oranges2()
    For Each r In Columns(2).SpecialCells(2)
        If r.Value = "OR" Then
            r.Offset(0, -1).Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
            r.Offset(0, -1).Clear
        Else
            r.Offset(0, 1) = 0
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so Much for this.  It's nearly there.  I only want to move the OR figure - leave the other figures in the original column. I would welcome your solution.

Comment: @Suz50  I don't understand

Comment: Column C would look like this

Comment: @Suz50  Update your original question with a picture

Comment: Can't work out how to imbed/paste a png image.

Comment: @Suz50  Do you want the **numbers** associated with *OR* just "moved over" and the other rows in column **C** to have zeros ??

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Suz50  See my **EDIT#1**